# Django models - at least one in many to many

Tags: python, django, validation, model, many-to-many

How can I ensure that at least one many to many relation is set?

For example: If I have a `listing` model which has a *image* field with a many to many relation to `images`. How can I ensure that at least one image is set

Bonus question: What if the minimum was something other than one? What about a maximum?

Comment: What do you mean by ensure? Prevent saving unless there's the required number of images?

Comment: Yes, making sure at least one is present (and if possible have a maximum as well)

Comment: Do you need it to filter Listings or somewhere else? While filtering, you can use annotation and filter by resulting number.

Comment: According to [this answer][1] this is not possible.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480322/enforce-at-least-one-value-in-a-many-to-many-relation-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a function to check if the `Listing` instance has at least one image instance, and connect that function to the `Listing` model's [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders)

It'll be something like, (assuming you are using django 1.3)

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Listing
...
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Listing)
def check_image_requirement(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.images.count() == 0:
        raise your_own_exception("Listing is required to have at least one image")
```

where you need to implement your_own_exception

**The following addition is the response to PO's further questions**

Implementing `Listing.clean()` is another way to achieve the same validation rule. Indeed, it's the semantically correct approach as `Model.clean()` is meant for custom model validations. But adopting this approach would be less convenient - to trigger the `clean()` you would have to either manually call `full_clean()` (if you don't use model form), or manually call `is_valid()` (when using model form), right before calling `save()` of a Listing instance. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean)

On the other hand, with the `pre_save` signal approach, you can be certain that the validation rule is always applied on `Listing` instance whenever you call `save()` on the instance.

It's not a right-or-wrong to choose one over the other but merely a design decision to make. Both approaches can achieve what you need and keep the business/domain logic (ie. your validation rule) in the Models layer.

Comment: I'm quite new to phython/django. Is pre_save ran before field validation (before making sure for example that an integer field is integer, or that a foreign key constraint matches)? Why pre_save and not clean()? When using a clean(), am I overwriting field validation or extending it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RS7 - No worries. Everyone is here to learn, including myself. I have added to my answer in response to your further questions.

Comment: Thanks, very informative -- last question: What if the `listing` model had many images represented by the `image` model. If I understood the docs correctly, instead of a manytomany field `images`, I'd create a separate model yes? So to check if the minimum is met, I'd access it the same way? `self.image.count()` if I was doing in `clean()`?

Comment: @RS7 - It depends. If all you need is a simple manytomany relationship (ie. no need to record additional attributes about the association), then all you need is a `ManyToManyField`. Say, you decided to set an expiry date (ie. an additional attribute) on the association, then you would need a `ManyToManyField`, plus an additional model representing the association/relationship. I highly recommend you to go over [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). The first paragraph basically reiterates what I just explained.

Comment: @RS7 - Yes, `self.image.count()` still applies in `clean()`

Comment: I was looking at the docs and I was wondering -- why `image.count()` and not `len(image)`?

Comment: `images` here is a QuerySet. Extracted from the official docs, "Don't use `len()` on QuerySets if all you want to do is determine the number of records in the set". [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Comment: Last question: I've moved the m2m image field to another model, named Images. When I try to access it in `clean()` it gives me an attribute error, saying that the `listings` object has no attribute `image` -- which makes sense. How can/would I access/validate this relation? Cheers

Comment: @RS7 - try `images_set` instead of `image`. On a side note, as a model naming convention, stick with singular, so you might want to use `Image` instead of `Images` for your model. If you make that change, it would be `image_set` that you need to try.

Comment: How does this work if you cannot assign a relation before an object is saved? When the object is initially saved it will not have any relations, because you cannot add any before it is saved, therefore this handler would always fail. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dcgoss - The answer is it depends. What you said is true if and only if all Listing data in the DB is created via the `Listing` model. The Listing data, however, could be inserted/created through other means, such as loading data via fixture, using some proxy model to the `Listing` model or etc.

Comment: If I do `self.mym2m.count()` in `clean()` I get `ValueError: <myinstance> needs to have a value for field "modelname" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`