# Enforce at least one value in a many-to-many relation, in Django?

Tags: django, orm

I have have a many-to-many relation in a Django(1.4) model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

I want to enforce that each User(Profile) has at least one Foo.  Foos can have zero-or-more User(Profiles)s.

I would love this to be enforced at the model and admin levels, but just enforcing it in the admin would be sufficient.

If I understand correctly, 'many' in Django-speak is zero-or-more.

I want a ManyToOneOrMore relation.  How can I do this?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't enforce this on at the model level as @Greg details, but you *can* enforce it on a form by simply making the field required. This won't prevent anyone with shell-level access from manually creating a UserProfile without a foo, but it will force anyone using a browser-based form method of creation.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible at the model level because ManyToMany data is saved separately from other model fields. You should be able to enforce it at the admin level by specifying a custom form, and writing a clean() method on the form.