# Enforce at least one value in many-to-one relationship's 'one' part

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-many

Suppose I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # ...

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass
```

I want to ensure that, whenever I create/save a `Manufacturer`, there is at least one `Car` belongs to that `Manufacturer`.

A very similar question about many-to-many relationships asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10480322/2275286) and the answer was no, at least through django-models. Only through a form, one can enforce such constraint. I'd like to learn whether it is valid for many-to-one as well.

The example above is from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Comment: How can you create a Car before you save the Manufacturer?

Comment: A very valid question. I can't unless the FK is allowed to be null, which I don't want it to be. I simply don't want to allow saving a Manufacturer without attaching a Car. It looks like it is not possible unless I use a form that enforces valid entries for both.

Comment: You can't enforce this from a database point of view, but as a workaround, you can write a custom manager (or override the default `objects` manager) that excludes Manufacturer instances with no cars from your relevant queries. This way you will still have the Manufacturer in your database but it won't show up in any reports.